# IE6,7 on a link hover, absolute positioning not changing on child

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```
<div id="topdevelopments" class="colnm colw6 clearfix">
    <a href="homes-for-sale/development/beaufort-park-6/" class="colnm agreen colw2"> 
        <img src="wp-content/themes/philosophy/images/noimage/212x153.png" width="212" height="153" alt="No Image" title="No Image" />
        <span class="popup"> 
            <span class="first">Recent development</span> 
            <span class="heading">Beaufort Park 6</span> 
        <span class="content">1, 2 & 3 bedroom apartments available from £160,000</span> 
        </span> 
        <span class="ir corner">&nbsp;</span> 
        <span class="ir go">&nbsp;</span> 
    </a> 
    <a href="homes-for-sale/development/beaufort-park-5/" class="col apurple colw2"> 
        <img src="wp-content/themes/philosophy/images/noimage/212x153.png" width="212" height="153" alt="No Image" title="No Image" />
        <span class="popup"> 
            <span class="heading">Beaufort Park 5</span> 
            <span class="content">1, 2 & 3 bedroom apartments available from £160,000</span> 
        </span> 
        <span class="ir corner">&nbsp;</span> 
        <span class="ir go">&nbsp;</span> 
    </a> 
    <a href="homes-for-sale/development/beaufort-park-4/" class="col ablue colw2"> 
        <img src="wp-content/themes/philosophy/images/noimage/212x153.png" width="212" height="153" alt="No Image" title="No Image" />
        <span class="popup"> 
            <span class="heading">Beaufort Park 4</span> 
            <span class="content">1, 2 & 3 bedroom apartments available from £160,000</span> 
        </span> 
        <span class="ir corner">&nbsp;</span> 
        <span class="ir go">&nbsp;</span> 
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topdevelopments {

}
    #topdevelopments a {
        border:#4D4D4D 10px solid;
        display:block;
        color:#fff !important;
        font-family:"MetaPlusBookRoman", sans-serif;
        font-size:16px;
        height:153px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:relative;
        width:212px;
    }
        #topdevelopments a span { display:block; }
        #topdevelopments a span.popup {
            height:133px;
            left:0px;
            overflow:hidden;
            padding:10px;
            position:absolute;
            top:153px;
            width:192px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }
        #topdevelopments a:hover span.popup { top:0px; }
        #topdevelopments a.agreen span.popup { background-color:#C1D82F; }
        #topdevelopments a.ablue span.popup { background-color:#36A6E8; }
        #topdevelopments a.apurple span.popup { background-color:#C6168D; }
        #topdevelopments a span.popup .first {
            font-family:"MetaPlusBlackRoman", sans-serif;
            font-size:20px;
            opacity:0.5;
        }
        #topdevelopments a span.popup .heading {
            border-bottom:#fff 2px solid;
            font-family:"MetaPlusBlackRoman", sans-serif;
            font-size:20px;
            margin-bottom:5px;
        }
        #topdevelopments a span.corner {
            background:url(images/corner/corner-dgrey.png);
            bottom:0px;
            height:40px;
            position:absolute;
            right:0px;
            width:40px;
        }
        #topdevelopments a span.go {
            bottom:4px;
            height:16px;
            position:absolute;
            right:4px;
            width:16px;
        }
        #topdevelopments a.agreen span.go { background-image:url(images/go/go-green.png); }
        #topdevelopments a.ablue span.go { background-image:url(images/go/go-blue.png); }
        #topdevelopments a.apurple span.go { background-image:url(images/go/go-purple.png); }
        #topdevelopments a.agreen:hover span.go { background-image:url(images/go/goh-green.png); }
        #topdevelopments a.ablue:hover span.go { background-image:url(images/go/goh-blue.png); }
        #topdevelopments a.apurple:hover span.go { background-image:url(images/go/goh-purple.png); }
```

What should happen is that when the "A" is hovered the "span" that is absolutely positioned out of the view should come into view by changing the "top" parameter. This works but in IE6 and IE7 only does it fail to work. I cannot figure out why. Anyone know why?

I'll add that each of the "A" links are floated left.

Comment: Any chance of a live link? Could you replicate the problem using [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: @thirtydot - I would normally add a link but this is a private development and is not ready for the eyes of the public yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add:

```
#topdevelopments a:hover {
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

IE likes a rule on the `a:hover` before it will activate an extension of it e.g `a:hover span`

anything will do as long as it's not already declared on the `a` rule

i.e. I picked `text-indent: 0` as it is a default that is not already on the `a` rule

Comment: Interesting I didn't know this. Another IE bug that I'll add to my data bank. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I created this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7H4n/3/).  I think you were missing `:hover` on `#topdevelopments a span.go`.

**Edit** although that appears to work, you lose the cursor icon on the links that appear!  You could possibly rectify that with more CSS but it seems a bit messy.  If the other solution works it might be more elegant.

Comment: I didnt miss the :hover on `#topdevelopments a span.go` its a few more lines down... Regarding the cursor icon issue it has been easily rectified by adding `cursor:pointer;` to `#topdevelopments a span`

Comment: The fiddle I linked to seems to work in IE7 - all I added was the :hover on the rule I mentioned above.  However the accepted answer seems to have the same effect anyway.  The problem with both is that you don't get the proper cursor for the link even though the link works.  I suspect further CSS could rectify that problem.